# Is it possible to create a Unity Component without adding it to a GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to create a Joint component separately before I add it as a component onto a GameObject. Is this possible/recommended? If it's possible but not recommended, why?

Comment: All components must be attached to Game Objects.

Comment: You could make a static class that other components reference, they can then share variables...

Comment: Do you mean a physics Joint? Yes, it is possible (a lot of Unity component have their constructor marked as internal, but is not the case with Joints). If your game needs to create joints in runtime and then attach those components to some gameObjects, I would not think that is not recommended (For example in Katamari Damacy you would create joints and configure those joints according to the game progress).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Unity is designed, every Component *must* be attached to a GameObject.

However, you might be interested in designs such as the [singleton pattern](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton), where your script automatically creates exactly one copy of a Component, which can potentially be shared across all scripts in all of your scenes.